# Can not execute sudo or gksudo comand to run nautilus to edit root file on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: nautilus, root

```
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(nautilus:3041): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```